# access printer with static IP in a different network

Tags: routing, subnet

A printer was sent out to a location with a static IP from its previous location.

Printer 123 was on subnet 192.168.5.0/24 in Branch A with a static IP of 192.168.5.5. Printer 123 was sent to branch B with a different network 172.16.4.0/24, BUT the static IP from branch A was never removed from Printer 123. Now it is sitting in Branch B with a static IP from its old network. How can I access the web interface to change it to DHCP?

Proposed solution:
If I place the switch port that the printer is connected to on its own vlan and place the vlan IP on its same network but a 192.168.5.0/30 (4 IP's 2 usable)just enough to cover the printer's static IP so it can be accessed, would that cause any issues with the routing tables? There is already a route that points traffic to 192.168.5.0/24 out a particular interface. The majority of the traffic (95%) from this branch forwards to branch A.

Would my solution work? is there an easier way? Apparently restoring to default does not work, then again I do not have an IT guy out there to ensure it actually is being restored to default settings.

Comment: my org is 100% cisco shop, all cisco routers and switches.

Comment: You really need to be careful about adding a network that is part of an existing network. The more specific network will be preferred. Also, your `192.168.5.0/30` will not cover the `192.168.5.5` address of the printer. You would need to use `192.168.5.4/30`, and you will need to set up routing to be able to get to that network. Anything needing to get to any of the four addresses in the existing network will go to the new network you create since it is a more explicit network.

Comment: Having run into an almost identical situation before, the real solution was to send the printer to someplace else to get it configured, then send it back to the new location.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution 1

IF it is ok for branch B to loose access to 192.168.5.0/24 temporarily, then on the branch B router's LAN interface  configure a secondary ip address 192.168.5.X (this needs to be the gateway configured on the printer!). Then configure a static /32 route for 19.168.5.5 on all hops between you and branch B, pointing to branch B (or have the router at B inject a /32 into your routing protocol.

Instead of using a secondary address you could also create a new vlan interface as you said, and put the printer in that vlan, but it cannot be a /30 (unless the printer's gateway happens to be .6 which seems very unlikely) so you probably just want the full /24 and make sure it is not redistributed in your routing protocol, and then inject a /32 again.

Solution 2

Use vnc, rdp etc. to remotely control a PC in branch B. Configure a secondary ip address 192.168.5.x on its nic. Then access the printer GUI from there.

Comment: solution two was magic, I don't know why I did not just think of this one. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use 802.1Q (QinQ) tunnelling to reach your printer.

you can find example: [here](https://networklessons.com/switching/802-1q-tunneling-q-q-configuration-example/)

Comment: Link only answers are discoured here. Please consider adding more information to your answer.